# Append HTML in DOM, not seen by selectors

Tags: javascript, dom

Using `innerHTML` when I add a new item, the query selector does not seem to add it.

So when I try to calculate my items. I only am getting the original ones to calculate, but not the newly generated ones.

Even when you `console.log()` the elements by the variable it will only show the original elements.

All these elements have the same class name as the original element.

Just cannot get them to be seen or added on the generated items.

Fiddle [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/d27gut8b/4/).

```
const total = document.querySelectorAll(".tot")
const price = document.querySelectorAll(".cost");
let textval = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-item');
const cal = document.getElementById("calc");
const errorMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.error');
//
let theform = document.querySelector(".theform");
let newitem = document.querySelector('.new-item');
let createBtn = document.getElementById("create");
let theItem = document.querySelector(".newStuff");
//


form.addEventListener("click",function(e){

let theHtml = `
 <div>
      <span class="cost">${newitem.value}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qty">
      <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
      </div>
      <div class="tot">
      <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
    </div>
`


});

cal.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  console.log('total', total);
  for (var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    let xPrice = price[i].innerHTML.split("$");
    let parsePrice = parseFloat(xPrice[1]);
    if (textval[i].value === "" || isNaN(textval[i].value)) {

   console.log("No Good");

    } else {
      let x = parseFloat(textval[i].value);
      let y = parsePrice;

      let z = x * y;

      total[i].innerText = z.toFixed(2);


      total[i].innerText = z;

      for (let k = 0; k < total.length; k++) {
        let j = parseFloat(total[k].innerHTML);

        console.log(j);

      }
    }
  }
});
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <span class="title">A Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="cost">$100.00</span>
    </div>
    <div id="qty">
      <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
      <p class="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tot">
      <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="main">
    <span class="title">A Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="cost">$50.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qty">
      <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
      <p class="error"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tot">
      <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class ='theform'>
 <label>NewItem</label><input placeholder="0" class="new-item">
  <button id="create">create</button>
  </form>

  <span class ="newStuff"></span>

  <div class="calc-button">
    <button id="calc">Calculate Prices</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: [_"The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a **static (not live)** NodeList"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). In other words, your `querySelectorAll` calls execute once, calculating the matching elements only at that time

Comment: ^... + the form is submitted when clicking one of those buttons, and the page is refreshed as the server response.

Comment: @Phil That explains it, is there a work around for this? I tried removing the event function than re-adding but that didnt work.

Comment: @Teemu the page is not refreshed as I have prevent-default enabled this is just front-end

Comment: Where? Not in the provided code ..? Also, you're just assigning the HTML to a JS variable, there's nothing which would append the HTML string to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phil is right on this.  You are running the query selectors at the start of your script and will therefore run only once.  So when the user clicks a button and you dynamically add new html to the page, the query selectors will not fire again.

You can initialize those queries at the top of your script just like you have them now, but you will need to re-assign their values to new queries inside your event listener something like the following:

```js
const total = document.querySelectorAll(".tot")
const price = document.querySelectorAll(".cost");
let textval = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-item');
let cal = document.getElementById("calc");
const errorMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.error');
//
let theform = document.querySelector(".theform");
let newitem = document.querySelector('.new-item');
let createBtn = document.getElementById("create");
let theItem = document.querySelector(".newStuff");

form.addEventListener("click",function(e){

let theHtml = `
 <div>
      <span class="cost">${newitem.value}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qty">
      <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
      </div>
      <div class="tot">
      <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
    </div>
`
//append your HTML to the correct target element then update your query inside the event listener

 textval = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-item');
 cal = document.getElementById("calc");
});
```

Comment: So you are saying to put the selectors, in the append function? So this will refresh the node list?

Answer (score 0):

Given all your `querySelectorAll()` queries are using simple, single-class-name selectors, you can replace them all with [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), ie

```js
const total = document.getElementsByClassName('tot')
const price = document.getElementsByClassName('cost');
const textval = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-item');
const errorMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
```

This behaves almost the same as `querySelectorAll()` with one difference...

> elements is a **live** HTMLCollection of found elements.

The elements referenced in these collections will update automatically as elements are added or removed from the document.